# Convert SQL dateTime return 0 or emptyString

Tags: mysql, sql, sql-server, sql-server-2008

I've tried some of the stackOverflow solution but still I get '1/1/1900'

in my actual database the postDate has a:

```
------------
|postedDate|
------------
  <NULL>
```

I've to create a query that looks like this, thinking that this would return a '0' but it doesn't, still I would return a '1/1/1900' value to me.

```
ISNULL(postedDate, CASE WHEN postedDate = '1/1/1900' THEN 0 ELSE postedDate END)

------------
|postedDate|
------------
 1/1/19000
```

I need a result that somehow looks like this:

```
------------
|postedDate|
------------
     0
```

or something like this:

```
------------
|postedDate|
------------
    N/A
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

SQL results are typed.  0 is not a date but can be converted to one (1/1/1900).  If you want 0 in the results, you'll have to have SQL return a string instead of a date.  You can do this by casting the date to a string, like this:

```
SELECT (CASE WHEN postedDate IS NULL THEN '0' ELSE CAST(postedDate AS VARCHAR(MAX))) postedDate ...
```

Comment: Thanks with your explanation, I Understand how this works.

Answer (score 0):

Converting an empty string (`''`) or `0` to a `DATETIME` results to the minimum value, that is why you're still getting `1/1/1900`. You should `CONVERT` your `DATETIME` to `VARCHAR`.

```
SELECT
    PostedDate = CASE 
                    WHEN PostedDate IS NULL THEN 'N/A'
                    ELSE CONVERT(PostedDate, VARCHAR(10), 101)
```

Comment: this explanation also helps thanks alot.